# Can't change MAC Address in El Capitan

Tags: network, macos, mac-address

I read the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151986/71015) and tried to change my Mac's en0 MAC address. When I use `ifconfing`, it reports the newly set MAC address, but in Network Settings, it still reports the old one.

Using `ifconfig`:
[image]

In Wi-Fi dropdown:
[image]

I tried turning Wi-Fi on and off (using `sudo ifconfig en0 up`/`down`), still the same. Am I doing something wrong or is this a part of [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193368/71015) introduced in El Capitan?

The reason I think my MAC address hasn't changed, is that I use bandwidth restrictions using UniFi AP, but changing my MAC address doesn't seem to contravene those restrictions.

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to System Integrity Protection (SIP), as this only affects the ability to change `/System` and other files. Computer wide settings such as networking preferences and options are not affected by SIP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with SIP because the fact is you cannot change the actual physical MAC Address of a NIC in that manner as it is encoded in it's EPROM. You can *spoof* a MAC Address in that manner however the actual physical MAC Address of a NIC will always be that of which it was programmed until reprogramed in the EPROM. I changed my MAC to what yours reports, while ifconfig shows the *spoofed* address the actual physical MAC Address remains as it was originally programmed. Wireshark is reporting the spoofed address but that doesn't stop a hardware verification app that polling the actual physical hardware for its address from seeing the real address.

Comment: Yes, thank you. MAC address shown in Networking dropdown shows the physically hardcoded address, not the spoofed one. (Actually I found a buggy configuration with my UniFi AP and fixed that too!)

Comment: I use [SpoofMac](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC). Works great.

Answer (score 6):

I understand you are looking to actually change your MAC address, but in case you want to spoof it to appear as another MAC address, this is what I recommend:

Use [SpoofMac](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC). It just works. Here is how to get it and use it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC.git
$ cd SpoofMAC
$ python setup.py install
$ cd scripts
$ python spoof-mac.py list
- "Ethernet" on device "en0" with MAC address 3C:07:54:55:71:41
- "FireWire" on device "fw0" with MAC address A4:B1:97:FF:FE:9E
- "Wi-Fi" on device "en1" with MAC address 68:A8:6D:1B:FE:E4 currently set to 00:E0:B8:1B:FE:E4
$ python spoof-mac.py set 00:00:00:00:00 en1 # or whatever mac address you want
```

Hope that helps anyone trying to change their perceived mac address and failing.

Comment: Works fine for me. Thank you! The only difference is that that needs to use the `set` command to change:
Usage:
    spoof-mac list [--wifi]
    spoof-mac randomize [--local] <devices>...
    spoof-mac set <mac> <devices>...
    spoof-mac reset <devices>...
    spoof-mac normalize <mac>
    spoof-mac -h | --help
    spoof-mac --version

Edited the answer with this change.

Comment: @BrunoCandidoVolpatodaCunha great! Glad it worked.

Comment: No need to clutter up your system, just run `brew install spoof-mac` and then `sudo spoof-mac randomize en1`

Comment: @Barry nice glad to see it is homebrew. Cheers