# MacBook Air Mid 2013 Wi-Fi MAC Address

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

If I change my network interface card on my MacBook Air 2013, which I assume to be my AirPort/Bluetooth card, will it change my laptop's MAC Address?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct; it will change.

Your MAC ([Media Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)) address is assigned to network interfaces, not to the computer.  For example, on this WiFi adapter from a Macbook Pro, you can see the MAC address imprinted on the chip (circled in red)

[image]

You can even lookup the manufacturer of the WiFi adapter by entering the first six characters into a lookup tool like [this one](https://www.adminsub.net/mac-address-finder/58b035).  In this case, "58b035" comes back as "Apple, Inc"

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that if you need to access something using a certain MAC address that it can be [temporally changed](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151986/change-mac-address-in-os-x-yosemite).