# How to permanently change my MAC address in macOS?

Tags: macos, mac-address

In macOS Sierra, for some reasons, I would like to change my MAC address and I would like that this change survive a reboot.

How can I do this?

Comment: Spoofing a MAC address is temporary as you can't actually change it.  *Why* do you need to have the same address?

Comment: Because I use a network where there is a fixed association between IP address and MAC address, and I also need to keep the same IP address.

Comment: So, there's some sort of accounting and authentication in place like RADIUS.  What you ***should*** do is contact your help desk or support organization, let them know that the adapter is lost.  They will update the system with you new MAC address.

Comment: You're right and that's what I've already done. This a temporary trick.

Comment: You want to "permanently" change your MAC address, as a "temporary trick"? After already taking the correct approach? I am confused!

Comment: Here "permanently" means "survive a reboot".

Answer (score 8):

If you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), install [SpoofMAC](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC) with

```
brew install spoof-mac
```

You can also install SpoofMAC with [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip), or directly with:

```
git clone git://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC.git
cd SpoofMAC
python setup.py install
```

Add a *local.macspoof.plist* file in */Library/LaunchDaemons*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>MacSpoof</string>    
            <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
            <string>/usr/local/bin/spoof-mac.py</string>
                <string>set</string>
                <string>ca:fe:ca:fe:ca:fe</string>
                <string>en4</string>
            </array>   
            <key>RunAtLoad</key>
            <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Adapt the interface name and address to your need then reboot.

Then load the launch daemon:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.macspoof.plist
```

P.S.: There is a similar question [Change MAC address in OS X Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151986/change-mac-address-in-os-x-yosemite) but the question is not about permanent change and is only for Yosemite.

Comment: You can't *permanently* change a MAC address by spoofing.

Comment: It change the MAC address at each boot. So it's kind of permanent. But effectively if you remove the plist file the "hardware" MAC address comes back.

Comment: Or if you boot into Safe Mode, or from the Recovery Partition, or from Internet Recovery.  If your Mac goes sideways for any reason, when you try to do Internet Recovery, you will find yourself locked out of access.

Comment: This will not be the case because I've Internet access without MAC address control.

Comment: Any particular reason why to use `en4`? I used `en0`because that's where my WI-FI interface is, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: How can I check that it's been changed, `networksetup -listallhardwareports` shows my default address, and also does **Netword Preferences**

Comment: What's the advantage of `macspoof` compared to `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

MAC address is always fixed based on the hardware NIC interface. You can spoof the Mac address but it wouldn't be ensured that it will remain spoofed with latest software updates etc.