# Wifi connection but no internet

Tags: macos, wifi, dns

I have joined my home WiFi network and I don't get Internet through it anymore. Phones and other computers have no issues, others who were here haven't  changed anything or noticed any difference.

I was away from home for a week using various public and hotel WiFi networks, if that means anything. I used a public WiFi network 30 minutes before and had no issues.

I've looked through previous questions like this which had a lot of responses, and I still haven't solved it:

[Full Wi-fi/ethernet signal but no internet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177873/full-wi-fi-ethernet-signal-but-no-internet)

[How do I troubleshoot my Wi-Fi connection when an exclamation mark appears?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49082/how-do-i-troubleshoot-my-wi-fi-connection-when-an-exclamation-mark-appears)

I can log in to the router admin settings. Everything seems fine.
I have tried changing the IPv4 address manually, making sure nothing is using the same IP etc.

I have tried using 8.8.8.8 as the DNS server address.
In Terminal `ifconfig en1` gives:

```
Flags=963<UP BROADCAST SMART RUNNING PROMISC SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
Options =60 <tso4, tso6>
Ether 4a:00:03:a0:13:90
Media: auto select <full-duplex>
Status: inactive
```

(Apologies if the syntax is off, I'm copying this on to my phone)

It is a MacBook Pro retina 13inch 2.9ghz i5, OSX 10.11.4

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless device appears to be in promiscuous mode.  Maybe you are doing a packet dump or sniffing packets?  If so, no worries.  If not, I would investigate this further, as it *sometimes* yet not always indicates a compromised system being used as a stepping stone in further network penetration.

First, a quick and dirty network device refresh can be effectuated by creating a new location in the System Preferences, under the network portion.  Look at the top, and under location, click edit locations.  Then click the plus button, and give the new location a name.
Then please select your home network, and re-enter the password.

Your problem might have been resolved.  If not, then please go back to the terminal and provide the output of these:

```
     ifconfig -a -v

     pfctl -v -si

     pfctl -v -sr

     ipconfig getpacket en1

     netstat -nvia -I en1

     netstat -nr
```

Hope that this helps.

F.

Comment: I am not sniffing packets as far as I know. I tried the new location suggestion but it did not help. I have the terminal outputs for the commands you gave but I will have to wait until tomorrow to get to a computer that I can post from. Thank you for your help.